# Convert txt files in a folder to rows in csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 100 txt files in a folder. I would like to create a csv file in which the content of each text file becomes a single row (actually, a single cell in a row) in this csv file. So, the result would be a csv file with 100 rows.

I tried the following code:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob('neg/*')

with open("neg.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

This create a csv with over thousands of rows since each txt file contains multiple paragraphs. Any suggestion?

Comment: what do you want to do with the line breaks in the original files?

Comment: I just want to ignore line breaks. Just a space between paragraphs would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How many lines in the files? Is each line then one field in the csv? Are each line in each file the same meaning in each file?

Comment: About 50 short sentences in each txt file. I would like to convert the whole content of each file to a single row in csv file. Ideally, the whole content to be a single cell in csv. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import glob
import csv

read_files = glob.glob('neg/*')

with open("neg.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    w=csv.writer(outfile)
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            w.writerow([line for line in infile])
```

That makes each line a cell in the output and each file a row.

If you want each cell to be the entire contents of the file, try:

```
import glob
import csv

read_files = glob.glob('neg/*')

with open("neg.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    w=csv.writer(outfile)
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            w.writerow(" ".join([line for line in infile]))
```

Comment: This does not return the right outputs. Instead, it writes the name of txt file in each row in csv.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @dawg, but now each cell contains a single character.

Comment: The content of a cell looks like this: "p,l,o,t, ,:, ,t,w,o, ,t,e,e,n, ,c,o,u,p,l,e,s, ,g,o, ,t,o, ,a, ,c,h,u,r,c,h, ,p,a,r,t,y,"

Comment: w.writerow([" ".join([line.strip() for line in infile])])

Comment: @RAVI, thank you guys. w.writerow([" ".join([line.strip() for line in infile])]) makes it work!

Answer (score 0):

Before writing each `line`, first do `line.replace('\n',' ')` to replace all new line characters with spaces.

Obviously, adjust your newline character according to your OS.